# Using git to track changes made on the server without commit

Tags: wordpress, git

Before I ask my question, I want to mention that I am only **today** starting to experiment with git, which therefore makes me a total git newbie.

I frequently work with graphic designers on Wordpress websites for clients.  After I upload the code to the server, the graphic designer sometimes edits the CSS & other files directly on the server using the Wordpress editor (within the Wordpress Admin panel).

You can imagine that this causes a problem for me, because I then have to first re-download all of the modified files to my local development folder -- and since I don't know which files were edited, I have to re-download the entire theme folder.  Then I make the changes locally, and re-upload to the server.

From what I read online, it seems Git could make this a  lot less painful.

**My question**: If the designer makes changes to files on the *server* using the wp editor **without** using git / commit, would using Git still help me? Would it download all of the modified files to my machine automatically, in a similar way that Dropbox works?

Comment: From reading more about `git`, can I just `pull` from my server's repository, and it'll automatically download the most recent files, even if changes were made without being committed / `git`ted ?

Comment: This is a terrible terrible workflow. Don't do this. Instead, help the designer set up a local wordpress install where they can commit and test changes, and/or a development clone of the real server. Server updates should be via `git pull` only.

Comment: @Daenyth has it right (though I think he meant `git push`).  The Designer should be working on a local installation and when everything is ready, the changes are pushed to the production site.  Uncontrolled edits happening ON the production site are asking for trouble.

Comment: @wadesworld: I mean that the developer should commit from his local machine only, and `git push` from there. The only `git` command the server should run is `pull` or `checkout`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing a git pull to move the files, wouldn't collect any changes from the working directory on the server.  A potential workflow might be to first log in to the server and commit all of the changes and push them to a bare repository.  You could then pull from the bare repository locally and see the changes that others have made and git will help you to merge them in to your local environment.

You could also deploy from your local environment to production in the same way, by pushing to the bare repository and then pulling from the bare repository to the production server.

The bare repo seems like an extra step, but both of your environments (the server and your local) are working environments, so transiting the bare repo will make it a little easier on you with committing and merging.  (If I'm off track on this one, I'm sure someone will point out the errors in my ways....)

You'll want to exclude the wp-config.php file from the repo, or modify the permissions site up based on environment variables or the like (ie set an environment variable in your vhost file locally and on the server and use a conditional statement to determine which DB credentials to use in wp-config.php).  Something like:

```
switch ($_SERVER['APPLICATION_ENV']) {
case 'local':
    define('DB_NAME', 'local');
    define('DB_USER', 'localuser');
    define('DB_PASSWORD', 'localpwd');
    define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
    define('WP_HOME','http://local.verycoolwebsite.com');
    define('WP_SITEURL','http://local.verycoolwebsite.com');
    define('WP_DEBUG', true);
    define('SAVEQUERIES', true);
break;

case 'production':
    define('DB_NAME', 'production');
    define('DB_USER', 'www');
    define('DB_PASSWORD', 'foobar');
    define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
    define('WP_HOME','http://www.verycoolwebsite.com');
    define('WP_SITEURL','http://www.verycoolwebsite.com');
    define('WP_DEBUG', false);
    define('SAVEQUERIES', false);
break;
}
```

It's also probably a good idea to exclude image directories if they are large and don't need version control.

As another option, take a look at the rsync command if what you are looking for is moving changes as opposed to full version control.

Comment: I'm still working on grasping my head around your answer, as it seems a little complicated to me given my basic understanding of `git`.  However, as you said, if I don't need version control, `rsync` would definitely be a good idea.  I forgot about this gem. +1

Comment: Slightly modified workflow might be to only then install git locally.  Rsync down the changes and commit them locally.  You'd still have to push your own changes up one by one (or reverse the rsync), but you'd have version control and a idea of what is changing.

Comment: I may resort to that. Unfortunately, it'll be too difficult for me to convince and teach the graphic designers that I work with to locally install wordpress and use `git`.  Using a combination of `git` and `rsync` sounds promising!